# function delete not work on mysql

Tags: laravel, controller

hay.. i have function delete on my controller ..  in client side when i am delete catagories is work.. but, when i check oh phpmyadmin. the categories still has not been deleted..
this is my categoriesController for delete..

```
 .........




    public function destroy(Request $request,$id)
        {
            try {
                DB::beginTransaction();

                $category = Category::find($id);
                $category->delete();

                $request->session()->flash('alert-success','Data successfully deleted');

                DB::commit(); 

                return redirect(route('categories.index'));
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                return Redirect::back()->with('error_message', $e->getMessage())->withInput();
            }  
        }
```

please help.. thanks

Comment: Add `$category->save();` after ` $category->delete();` in destroy method

Comment: @bimoan do you have `deleted_at` field/column at category table??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with below code:

```
//For delete category

DB::table('category')->where('id',$id)->delete();
```

**OR**

```
$category = Category::find($id);    
$category->forceDelete();
```

Comment: thanks its worked when i am using 
after I use the 2nd way

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
public function destroy($id) 
{
    $category = Category::destroy($id);
}
```